# SWF on the IOS applications from web url

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, flash

I had developed a mobile application for realestate company. They have a website and every thing are loading from the website. Now, they wants to add a virtual tour feature to their website. We are looking for a solution that be useful for both website and mobile platforms.

After many consults I thing making virtual tours with flash is a good item but there is a big concern. Do we can download swf files from internet and then user play them on the ios applications?

I heard that ios do not support swf files on their applications and even reject application with swf files. Is it true?

The scenario that I imagine is downloading swf virtual link from web and playing it under a tab at iphone and ipas. Is that possible and valid under ios ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Even Adobe themselves have given up on Flash on mobile devices.

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/06/flash-player-and-android-update.html

> We announced last November that we are focusing our work with Flash on PC browsing and mobile apps packaged with Adobe AIR, and will be **discontinuing our development of the Flash Player for mobile browsers**.

Android and iOS devices have no Flash playing capability, period. While you can author native apps using Adobe's tools, that's an entirely different and isn't going to be an option on a website.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know an tutorials or samples for authoring ios and android applications with these tools that your introduce? Also if they are just a tools for playing swf files so I can play them on website by website tools and on the mobiles by mobile tools. Yes?

Comment: You're going to be better off building a virtual tour sort of thing using HTML.